# longtable, \multicolumn and \boldmath

Tags: longtable

The following code does compile

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c}
  \noalign{\bfseries $r$ test}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Line 1}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

but this one does not

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c}
  \noalign{\bfseries\boldmath $r$ test}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Line 1}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I got the error message `misplaced \omit`. I have to double the braces:

```
\noalign{{\bfseries\boldmath $r$ test}}
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: note that even in the non-error case the markup is wrong latex is not set up to typeset a paragraph of text in `\noalign` you should always use a nested parbox or minipage or at least `\@parboxrestore` (`\par` is defined to do nothing, baseline spacing is zero....)

Comment: Can you show a context where this would be useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\boldmath` uses `\mathversion` that puts stuff after the current group via `\aftergroup`. Therefore, the macro `\glb@settings` is leaking out of `\noalign`, disturbing the table.

A group helps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c}
  \noalign{{\bfseries\boldmath $r$ test}}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Line 1}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]